# Mysql database for dynamic number of fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm using PHP 5.3 with MySQL 5.5 for development. My situation is like this:

- We have Users which are assigned to a group (n to 1 relation; every user has one group)
- Each group's users have their own fields and properties which is different from others. (we need to store these fields for each user)

So, in order to store dynamic fields, I created a `fields` table:

```
Fields:
  field_id
  group_id
  field_name
  field_type
```

Which holds field name and type for each group, and then I created a table for their values:

```
Field_Values
  user_id
  field_id
  field_value
```

But I want to know is this the best way?

What about creating a separate table for each group? Does it have any bad consequences? (because the queries would be easier I think) OR Is there any other efficient way to handle this?

Any useful information or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Create an EER Diagram of the relations and normalize it. So it's the most easy way to understand the stored data. What you're writing about seems to be more no-sql like

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. But how an EER diagram with multiple number of tables would look like? Could you give me any example resources? And about no-sql data, can mysql be used for storing such data?

Comment: Yes off course two columns key - > value and in value any data is serialized in a structure defined for the application handling with it

Comment: A separate table for each group would be bad.  The way you are showing things is on the right track.  How sure are you about the one to many relationship between users and groups?  That sounds suspicious to me.

Comment: Can I ask why is it bad? The separated relation is defined in the problem itself. I mean they don't need (and are not allowed) to have any interaction with other groups. But the main administrators may want to search among different groups.

Comment: Are you stuck with MySQL? Postgres has pretty cool "NoSQL" support for this kind of things through the `hstore` datatype. Essentially a key/value store which is extremely fast to search.

Comment: Thank you for your useful advice. I'll consider it as an option. BTW, I need to read some resources regarding the `hstore` as I've never worked with these NoSql things! Do you have any?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try viewing it as a document store? Use the user id as the key and then store the fields as JSON (or XML). Then you'd have a single group per user but the fields could be totally unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a good idea but what about searching queries? The manager of each group should be able to search through its users easily. Wouldn't this make it hard to query the entities based on a special field?

Answer (score 1):

> I think you are on the right path . I would probably would do similarly .

Tables:

```
group ( group_id ,group_name ,group_type ,... )

    1   group1
    2   group2

user ( user_id ,group_id ,user_name ,... )

    1   1   a
    2   1   b
    3   2   c

I am assuming users of one group share the same set of fields but have their own field values

field ( field_id ,group_id ,field_name ,field_type, field_active )

    1   1   field1
    2   1   field2
    3   2   field3

user_field_value ( field_value_id ,user_id, field_id ,field_value )

    1   1   1   value1
    2   1   2   value2
    3   2   3   value3
```

Creating separate table for each group would not be a good idea in the long term .

- It would become harder to maintain when you want to add more columns to those tables .
- When retrieving information , you would need to dynamically JOIN a different table based on the user_group .
- Etc .

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I don't get why it is bad. There are some improvements either, queries will be easier, all groups will be totally separated and easier backups will be available for each group. Does "having a lot of tables" bad?

Comment: Even if you have separate group tables for each group , I assume you would still have just one user table , just one user_field_value table , etc , so it is not total separation . Usually backups are made at database level . But if you need to have separate backups for each group , you would still need to pull information from just one user table , just one user_field_value table , etc . Unless you have any other very strong reason , having lots of tables with exact same structure would not be good idea while you could do with just one table .